# returning the first column value with two independent row criteria in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to return the first value in a table with two criteria.

My table:

```
          10             10.25         10.5            10.75            11  11.25   11.5    11.75   12  12.25   12.5
1   -60.48588181    -60.30316925    -60.12458801    -59.94994354    -59.77906418    -59.61178589    -59.44795227    -59.28742218    -59.13005829    -58.97573471    -58.82432938
2   -55.20667267    -55.01589584    -54.82941818    -54.64704514    -54.46858978    -54.29388428    -54.1227684 -53.95509338    -53.79071426    -53.62950134    -53.47133255
3   -51.99880981    -51.80309296    -51.61177444    -51.42465973    -51.24155807    -51.06229782    -50.88671112    -50.7146492 -50.54596329    -50.38052368    -50.21820068
4    -49.6653862    -49.4660759     -49.27124405    -49.08068466    -48.894207  -48.71163559    -48.53279877    -48.35755157    -48.18573761    -48.01722336    -47.85187912
5   -47.82113266    -47.61899948    -47.42140579    -47.22814178    -47.03900909    -46.85383606    -46.67245102    -46.49469376    -46.32041931    -46.14949036    -45.98177338
6   -46.29128647    -46.08683777    -45.88697052    -45.69148254    -45.50017166    -45.31285858    -45.12937164    -44.94955826    -44.77325821    -44.6003418 -44.43067169
7   -44.98129654    -44.77488708    -44.57309723    -44.37572479    -44.1825676 -43.99344254    -43.80817795    -43.62661743    -43.4486084 -43.27400589    -43.10267639
8   -43.83405685    -43.62594986    -43.42250061    -43.22349548    -43.02874374    -42.83805084    -42.65125275    -42.46818161    -42.28868866    -42.11262894    -41.93986893
9   -42.81235504    -42.60276031    -42.39785004    -42.19741821    -42.00126266    -41.80919647    -41.62104797    -41.43664932    -41.25585556    -41.07851791    -40.90449905
10  -41.89056015    -41.67964554    -41.47344208    -41.27173996    -41.07433701    -40.8810463 -40.69169998    -40.50612259    -40.32417297    -40.14569473    -39.97056198
```

lets say I want the search for a value in the first column, say 7. Then, I want to search across to say the value -44.37. The value I want returning would be 10.75. Is something like this possible in excel? I've tried the vlookup function but this is limited to one criteria search.

Any ideas?

Comment: With Excel formulas or VBA?

Comment: formula if possible

Comment: Thanks for your contribution....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(N5,ROUNDDOWN(INDEX(A:L,MATCH(N4,A:A,0),0),2),0))
```

being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.

This assumes you will always look for two significant figures after the decimal.

[image]

---

This formula will adjust the rounding to what ever it placed in the lookup cell:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(N5,ROUNDDOWN(INDEX(A:L,MATCH(N4,A:A,0),0),LEN(MID(N5,FIND(".",N5)+1,99))),0))
```

[image]

Comment: @if it wasn't for the need to round down the values to match, this would not need to be an array formula.  I first tried a wildcard match but since that tried to match a string to a number it did not work.

Comment: This technique is going in my toolbox.